# How to get number of rows in a grouped-by category in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In `pandas`, I have (`app_categ_events` is a `dataframe`):

```
> print(app_categ_events.label_id.unique().shape)
> print(app_categ_events.category.unique().shape)

Out:
(492,)
(458,)
```

I want to look at the `label_category`’s that have more than one `label_id` for each (because I thought there was supposed to be a one-to-one mapping).

In [r](/questions/tagged/r) `data.table`, I can do:

```
app_categ_events[, count_rows := .N, by = list(category, label_id)]
# (or smth of that sort...)
print(app_categ_events[counts_rows > 1])
```

What’s the best way of doing that in `pandas`?

Comment: In data.table, the short way is `DT[, if (.N > 1L) .SD, by=g]`, fyi, unless you want the `count_rows` var for some other reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We `transform` the dataset to create the 'count_rows' column after grouping by 'category', 'label_id'

```
app_categ_events['count_rows'] = app_categ_events.groupby(['category', 
                  'label_id'])['label_id'].transform('count')
print(app_categ_events)
#  category  label_id  count_rows
#0        a         1           2
#1        a         1           2
#2        b         2           1
#3        b         3           1
```

Now, the equivalent of `data.table` as showed in the OP's post would be

```
print(app_categ_events[app_categ_events.count_rows>1])
#    category  label_id  count_rows
#0        a         1           2
#1        a         1           2
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd;
app_categ_events = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'label_id': [1, 1, 2, 3]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) to return the desired results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label_id': [1, 1, 2, 3], 
                   'category': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})

df.groupby(['category']).filter(lambda group: len(group) > 1)
  category  label_id
1        b         1
2        b         2
```

Comment: Suppose you had multiple entries for `'a'` with the same corresponding `label_id`.  There is still a one-to-one correspondence, but I believe your answer picks it up anyway.

Comment: True, but I am expecting one-to-one mapping and thus no duplicates.  If there are duplicates, a simple `df.drop_duplicates()` before the groupby should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

***Given:***

```
app_categ_events = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                                 'label_id': [1, 1, 2, 3]})
```

***Solution:***

```
# identify categories with greater than 1 number of related label_id's
cat_mask = app_categ_events.groupby('category')['label_id'].nunique().gt(1)
cats = cat_mask[cat_mask]

# filter data
app_categ_events[app_categ_events.category.isin(cats.index)]
```

[image]